# What command do I use to get a listing of all my lists in Redis?

Tags: c#, redis

What is the best command to use to get a list of all my lists in Redis?

Comment: None seem to exist in the C# APIs that I'm aware of (BookSleeve and ServiceStack).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such a command.

You can create a **SET** of all of your keys that are lists, upon creating them. It might sound inefficient, but it's really OK, that's the nature of NoSQL databases. And speed is virtually not an issue, because one of the biggest advantages of Redis is being very very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Append or Prepend something to your lists, then use the KEYS command.

e.g. you have got:
list:mylist1
list:mylist2

> KEYS list:*

returns:
list:mylist1
list:mylist2

http://redis.io/commands/keys

Comment: Very slow if you have a lot of keys in Redis (and not necessarily lists). The proposal of using a set to track all lists is much better, IMO.